# Android: Combining AsyncTask with View (canvas)

Tags: android, view, android-asynctask, android-canvas

I'm trying to draw different random values from an array, but linking them with lines, so it looks likes the values of a continue function. I have done it quite good with this app:

```
package android.nacho.Graphic2D;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;


import java.util.Random;//included random

public class Graphic2D extends Activity{

    DrawView drawView;

    //private Button btnAsyncTask;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);           



int randomInt;

                    //note a single Random object is reused here
                    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
                    int Maxsize=800;
                    int[] randomNumbers= new int[Maxsize];

                    for (int idx = 1; idx < Maxsize-1; ++idx){

                        randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
                        randomNumbers[idx]=randomInt;

                        System.out.println("Random number: "+randomInt);
                    }



                         drawView = new DrawView(Graphic2D.this, randomNumbers, Maxsize);
                         drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                         setContentView(drawView);


    }

}


package android.nacho.Graphic2D;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;

public class DrawView extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    int[] values;
    int Size, Offset;

    public DrawView(Context context,  int[] datainBytes, int size) {
        super(context);
        values=datainBytes;
        Size=size;
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);




    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        int cont2;

        for(int cont=0; cont<Size-(1); cont++)
        {
            cont2=cont+1;
            canvas.drawLine(cont, 500-(values[cont]) , cont+1, 500-(values[cont2]), paint);         

        }



    }


}
```

The thing is, now I want to dram much more points, but in a dinamicall way so the new value is the one most at the right, the rest of the values move one pixel to the left and the one most of the left just don't appear. I was planning to this with a loop in the main Activity, so in each iteration the random values are all the same but the last one, and the others have move one position to the left in the array. The final effect should be something like a video.

But there is a problem, do App don't draw this dinamically, it just draw the last iteration of the loop. ¿Could anyone help me to solve this?

I was thinking in using AsyncTask for that, doing the points generation in the backgroun and sending the result to the update so draw in, but the script was a mess that didn't work, so I prefer to don't upload it.

Thank you very much for any suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know how it works.